# retrieving from a google calendar events using PHP api offline

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a site where users want to have their google calendar
All the examples seem to have the owner of the calendar authenticating each time.
Is there not a way to authenticate my app to get the users calendar data and display it?

I tried to save the `access_token` of the owner after they accepted my app but after a little while I got the following error:

```
The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.
```

This is the code I am trying (BTW the config.php has all the api stuff filled out)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true); 
$client->setApplicationName("My Unit Calendar");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($row['access_token'] ); //from the DB

$calService = new Google_CalendarService($client);

$events = $calService->events->listEvents( $row['google_cal_id'] ); //from the DB

echo "events--><pre>".print_r($events,true)."</pre>";
```

But I get the following Exception:

```
Google_AuthException-->The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Before get/set something from  Google you must check if access token is not expired and refresh it using refresh token, you got after first authorization (it is returned by `$client->getAccessToken()` ). I think, you want to do something, like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true); 
$client->setApplicationName("My Unit Calendar");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($row['access_token'] ); //from the DB

$calService = new Google_CalendarService($client);

checkToken($client, $row['refresh_token']); // Added function

$events = $calService->events->listEvents( $row['google_cal_id'] );

// Check if Access token is expired and get new one using Refresh token
function checkToken($client) {
    if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->refreshToken( $refresh_token );
    }
}
```

You must store in database refresh token you got when first time authorized and check if access token is not expired, if expired - refresh (for example in your `google_callback.php` file):

```
// Initialize access to Google
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId( *** );
$client->setClientSecret( *** );
$client->setRedirectUri( *** );
$client->setAccessType( *** );

// Initialize access to Calendar as service
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

// If isset code - set into session
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['google-api']['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}


// If in session is set token
if (isset($_SESSION['google-api']['access_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['google-api']['access_token']);
}


// If Access Token Expired (uses Google_OAuth2 class), refresh access token by refresh token
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken( /* Get refresh token from DB */);
}


// If client got access token successfuly - perform operations
$access_tokens = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

if ($access_tokens) {
    // Update refreshToken and save data if refresh token is received (logged in now)
    if(isset($access_tokens->refresh_token)) {
        // Store in DB refresh token - $access_tokens->refresh_token
    }
}
```